# Call a function and insert text in minibuffer prompt

Tags: minibuffer

I'd like to define a key binding that calls a function and inserts some default input in the function's minibuffer prompt. For example, I'd like to call the command `ivy-switch-buffer` and automatically insert `yank "!\*"` into the minibuffer.

(note: not really interested in alternative solutions to this particular example; would like a general solution)

Comment: IIUC your problem is the same as the one described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36118899/3084001). Note that I have suggested an edit to the accepted answer to use the convenience wrapper macro `minibuffer-with-setup-hook` instead of `minibuffer-setup-hook` directly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use minibuffer-setup-hook:

```el
(defun foo () (insert "ABCDE"))

(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook 'foo)
```

As @Basil mentions in a comment, depending on your use case you can alternatively use macro `minibuffer-with-setup-hook` (assuming it is available in your Emacs version).  It adds a function *temporarily* to `minibuffer-setup-hook`, then executes the code in its body.  You can use it if you just want a one-off use of a function on the hook.

```el
(minibuffer-with-setup-hook
    'foo
  (call-interactively #'ivy-switch-buffer))
```

Comment: (As @Basil said in a comment to your question, this is the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36118899/729907) on SO.  And my answer is the same.  In a way it's too bad we cannot deal with questions that are duplicates between different SE sites.))

Comment: I suggested [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17649957) to [your SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36122179/3084001) but it was rejected by a couple of moderators. I'm just curious, is there any reason to prefer manually modifying `minibuffer-setup-hook` over using the `minibuffer-with-setup-hook` macro? If not, perhaps you would consider mentioning the latter in your answer here, on the more specialised Emacs SE site.

Comment: @Basil: It's not the same thing. Whether you use it depends on your use case.

Comment: Indeed and thanks for mentioning it. I see it as analogous to `with-current-buffer` vs `set-buffer`: the wrapper macro covers the majority of use-cases (including OP's question) and provides added convenience and safety (e.g. via `unwind-protect`).