# Call function interactively and set initial content

Tags: minibuffer, commands

I would like to call a function (`find-file`) interactively and then set the initial content of the mini buffer to my server's home folder. I got as far as using `call-interactively`, but after that I'm lost. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a function and insert text in minibuffer prompt](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36208/call-a-function-and-insert-text-in-minibuffer-prompt)

Comment: If the question is specifically about find-file, please make it clear. Otherwise it should be closed as duplicate imo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`find-file` uses the buffer-local `default-directory` value as the default filename (see also `find-file-read-args`), so all you need to do is bind that value for the scope of the call to `find-file`:

```el
(let ((default-directory "/home/"))
  (call-interactively 'find-file))
```

Comment: Great! For reference is there any generic way to insert text into the mini-buffer programmatically when calling a function interactively?

Comment: Not sure if this is the best method, but you could wrap the function that you are calling in your own `interactive` function, creating the prompt yourself (with `read-string`, for example).  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9646268/3282436) answer for an example.

Comment: OP: The question you pose in your comment is the one posed [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/36208/105). The question about `find-file` inserting a directory name is a special case, which can be taken care of as @phils said. For that solution, however, be sure to have option `insert-default-directory` be non-`nil` (which it is by default). Otherwise, you can insert the directory into the minibuffer interactively, using `M-n`.