# How can I resume swiper-isearch with the next line selected?

Tags: minibuffer, ivy

What I'm trying to do is have `swiper-isearch` resume the last search with the next element selected. The definition of next is the next element from where my cursor currently is.

You can read my original post below for how I was trying to use `ivy-resume` and `ivy-next-line` to achieve this, but it didn't work — it always resumed with the originally selected item still pre-selected.

---

*Original Post:*

## How can I resume ivy with the next line selected?

I want to issue a keyboard command that resumes the last ivy listing, but instead of resuming at the line it left off at, I want to resume with the next line selected. I thought this would be simple enough if I did the following:

```el
(defun my-ivy-resume-with-next-line ()
  "Resume the last completion and move current line down one."
  (interactive)
  (ivy-resume)
  (ivy-next-line))
(global-set-key (kbd "s-g") 'my-ivy-resume-with-next-line)
```

When I hit my keyboard command, ivy resumes right where it left off — it does not go to the next line. I'm not sure if there's some simple elisp functionality that I should know to fix this, or if `ivy-resume` is doing something weird. My guess would be that maybe `ivy-next-line` is being called in my main buffer and not the newly created minibuffer from `ivy-resume`. (If that's the case, then this is a question of how to call that command in the context of the minibuffer.)

---

#### Notes:

I have also tried various variations of the following for the message body per suggestions in the comments:

`(minibuffer-with-setup-hook (:append #'ivy-next-line) (ivy-resume))`

Nothing seemed to work for me in my testing. However, after hearing they were working for others, I changed which function I was using to create the initial ivy listing and it worked. So the minibuffer hook is working for me when ivy has been called using `counsel-find-file` but not when using `swiper-isearch`. My primary use case for this is to resume swiper and go to the next found item, so I still need help.

---

Software versions

- swiper 20200220.1026
- ivy 20200220.1043
- Emacs 26.3
- MacOS 10.15.3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call a function and insert text in minibuffer prompt](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36208/call-a-function-and-insert-text-in-minibuffer-prompt)

Comment: TL;DR: `ivy-resume` does not return until after the minibuffer completion session has ended, by which point it is too late to call `ivy-next-line`, which you want called as soon as the minibuffer completion session starts. You can achieve this via `(minibuffer-with-setup-hook (:append #'ivy-next-line) (ivy-resume))`.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. It just resumes on the same line it was on, just like my original script.

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure you have reevaluated `my-ivy-resume-with-next-line` with its new definition, e.g. using `C-M-x`? When facing an issue in general, please update your question with a detailed set of steps to reproduce the issue, explaining what you expect and what you actually get at each stage, and which version of Emacs you are using; otherwise it is difficult to guess what is going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Updated my description. It turns out that my primary use-case (and what I was testing) didn't work, but other ivy completions did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution to what I was trying to do:

```el
(defun my-swiper-isearch-again ()
  "Start swiper-isearch with the last thing searched for."
  (interactive)
  (swiper-isearch (car swiper-history)))
(global-set-key (kbd "s-g") 'my-swiper-isearch-again)
```

Now when I press "s-g" the previous swiper search starts again from the point of the current cursor and moves then to the next item that matches the search.