# Create a function to run a search with mini-buffer partially completed

Tags: evil, search, minibuffer

I would like to write a function that starts a search (`evil-search-forward` specifically), with some arbitrary text already in the minibuffer.

Following [directions in this link](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36208/call-a-function-and-insert-text-in-minibuffer-prompt) I came up with the following:

```lisp
  (defun my/insert-headline-string ()
    (insert "foobar"))

  (minibuffer-with-setup-hook
      (:append 'my/insert-headline-string)
    (call-interactively #'evil-search-forward))
```

But it doesn't work for me: `evil-search-forward` runs just fine, but there is no text in the mini-buffer. If I use a different function (eg `find-file`) it prefills mini-buffer as expected, like so:

```lisp
  (minibuffer-with-setup-hook
      (:append 'my/insert-headline-string)
    (call-interactively #'find-file))
```

Is there a reason this won't work for the search minibuffer?

Comment: I don't use Evil, but did you try just using `insert` instead of `:append`? (Dunno what `:append` does.) And does `evil-search-forward` actually use the minibuffer? Isearch does not, for example, even though it looks like it does.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!
Looking into `evil-search-forward`, it's basically a wrapper for isearch, which explains why editting the minibuffer doesn't do what I want. Would there be a way to prefill the isearch minibuffer I wonder?
(Also, played with `insert` instead of `:append` but could not get that to work).

Comment: You ask how to *"prefill the isearch minibuffer"*. There is no Isearch minibuffer - that's what I said. But you can predefine ("prefill") the initial search string: `(defun the () (setq isearch-string "the")) (defun find-the ()(interactive) (add-hook 'isearch-mode-hook 'the) (isearch-mode t))`

Comment: That did it, thanks! I just added a `remove-hook` after the search to clean things up and it's just what I wanted. 
I can post the final code I'm using as an answer? Or do you want to? I don't know SE etiquette.

Comment: Sure. Please post your answer. (And you can accept your own answer.) Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Drew 's suggestions, I managed to achieve this with the following code:

```
  (defun my/set-isearch-string ()
    (setq isearch-string "^\*+[[:space:]].*"))

  (defun my/search-headlines-only ()
    (interactive)
    (add-hook 'isearch-mode-hook 'my/set-isearch-string)
    (evil-search-forward) 
    (remove-hook 'isearch-mode-hook 'my/set-isearch-string))
```